# python encoding and string value convert issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am totally new in python. i tried to do code. here is the code and images.

[image]

I have removed Quantity column so i have

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME     Store_Type  MonthInCalendar      NET_AMT
```

columns all are unique values

Info or data type of my column:

[image]

There is no null values i checked

some time i get suggestion label encoding some time one hot. i have three categorical variables. i do one hot encoding

```
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df4, columns=["DEPARTMENT_NAME", "Store_Type", "MonthInCalendar"])
X = df_encoded.drop("NET_AMT", axis=1).values
y = df_encoded["NET_AMT"].values
print(df_encoded.head())
```

After one hot I got X and y:

[image]

I did decision tree regression as i got best out come from here

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=10)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)

# Train a decision tree regression model with the best hyperparameters found by grid search
dt_clf = DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='friedman_mse', splitter='random')
dt_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
dt_score = dt_clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Decision Tree Regression Test Score:", dt_score)
```

Decision Tree Regression Test Score: 0.9750014483983159

then when i predict

```
prediction = dt_clf.predict(['Beef','Warehouse','22-Dec'])
print(prediction)
```

I got error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Beef'`

please help me to complete this work done.

thanks

I tried label encoding
I tried other regression models.
but no luck. i need to predict NET_AMT or Sales by using categorical variables

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME    Store_Type   MonthInCalendar
```

i got error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Beef'`

please help to complete

Comment: You will have to convert beef to its numerical representation as you did before training. Because your model does not understand strings, it only understands numerical values.

Comment: thats what i did. i tried one hot and also label encoding but no luck. i did encoding then train and test then when predict it give me string error. please help and tell me each steps one after another. even if i have to convert string to float in any step. i m new to python so please help me to resolve this issue. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @pavan, you have to hot encode any input like `['Beef', 'Warehouse', '22-Dec']` before predict `NET_AMT`. To do that, use [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html):

Replace:

```
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df4, columns=["DEPARTMENT_NAME", "Store_Type", "MonthInCalendar"])
X = df_encoded.drop("NET_AMT", axis=1).values
y = df_encoded["NET_AMT"].values
```

With:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

cols = ['DEPARTMENT_NAME', 'Store_Type', 'MonthInCalendar']
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
X = ohe.fit_transform(df[cols]).toarray()
y = df['NET_AMT'].values
```

And:

```
prediction = dt_clf.predict(['Beef','Warehouse','22-Dec'])
```

With:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Beef','Warehouse','22-Dec']], columns=cols)
prediction = dt_clf.predict(ohe.transform(df1).toarray())
```

Toy example (without `train_test_split`):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPARTMENT_NAME': ['Others', 'Poultry', 'Beef'], 
                   'Store_Type': ['Shop in Shop', 'E-Commerce', 'Warehouse'],
                   'MonthInCalendar': ['23-Jan', '23-Jan', '22-Dec'],
                   'NET_AMT': [10000, 20000, 30000]})

cols = ['DEPARTMENT_NAME', 'Store_Type', 'MonthInCalendar']
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
X = ohe.fit_transform(df[cols]).toarray()
y = df['NET_AMT'].values

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Beef','Warehouse','22-Dec']], columns=cols)
prediction = dt_clf.predict(ohe.transform(df1).toarray())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  DEPARTMENT_NAME    Store_Type MonthInCalendar  NET_AMT
0          Others  Shop in Shop          23-Jan    10000
1         Poultry    E-Commerce          23-Jan    20000
2            Beef     Warehouse          22-Dec    30000  # <- MATCH

>>> prediction
array([30000.])  # <- MATCH
```

Comment: I have done label encoding at first

then do train and test
then again hot encoding

please help me steps by stpes process to over come ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Beef' issue using decession tress regression model

Comment: Why do you encode twice? First split then fit and transform train dataset and finally train your model. In second time, transform test dataset then predict. Use a metric like RMSE to evaluate performance.

Comment: in my given issue i did those steps then why am i getting  ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Beef'. please explain bit elaborate. as i told i m totally new in python. i have tried in many google sites but couldn't find the solution. i did hot encoding then label then train and test then predict but same issue. i really can't where i made mistake. if some one can give me steps or example data with steps that would help me a lot. thanks guys

Comment: i tried a lot to fix this string conversion issue but no luck. please help me. please tell me what info you need .

Comment: Share your dataset and your code. Use Google Colab or share via Wetransfer, Dropbox, etc

Comment: can i share you one to one if u not mind to give me your email.

Comment: Upload a zip file and copy/paste the link here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Furfhe8BFbkEhXn1xcYPr8jYAACNpfV7p?usp=sharing
i have given one for decision tree one for artificial neuron network and one csv file. i am trying to read previous 12 months data and predict next month sales. for that i am still stuck at string to float conversation. if you could help me within your busy time would be great. i am really new and for learning reason i have done so many things also duplicate things in two files, hope you understand. and extensively request you if you can work both ANN and decision tree file to resolve my issues.

Comment: have you got my files? is it editable?

Comment: Your link doesn't work. 404 Error

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GKN74yRO46GqV9wKwntdIV37evozQwb2?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X0pGfI6CkAPE0GQb8yAiZ903LfLwXqcM?usp=sharing

Comment: please try now. i thing there is a time out option in google drive. please try now

Comment: I can't reproduce your error...

Comment: Dear Corralien,

What i mean is if you go all the way down and give following 

prediction = ann.predict(['beef', 'Gb Shop', '22-Dec'])
print(prediction)

it says string cant convert to float. and so i can do flask server to predict using actual user data

Comment: Hi Corralien,
i cant go further or predict by giving the user data like beef or warehouse or 22-dec etc. as it giving me string conversation error. please help me out from this so i can move further. i m really new to python world. and need help for this so i can create flask server.

Comment: Did you read my answer??? I explain how do you avoid this error. You can't use textual data as it, you have to encode them before predict.

Comment: would you mind to tell me how can i do encode before predict? i already done once before train and test if you please guide me or correct the code file will be great to u

Comment: so do i have to do two time encoding? one before train and test one after? just confirm me please

Comment: I checed and re-upload file with what i want.

I want to run following code as user level to predict.

predicted_price = dt_clf.predict('Beef', 'Warehouse', '22-Dec', 200000)
print(f"The predicted price for this item is ${predicted_price:.2f}")


for ANN

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X0pGfI6CkAPE0GQb8yAiZ903LfLwXqcM?usp=sharing

and

for decision Tree

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GKN74yRO46GqV9wKwntdIV37evozQwb2?usp=sharing

I am getting is when converting string value to float.

Comment: Please try: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RDcHSjQTY1vQHo4Fkrd7cGb4-bCJerO9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks Corralien,

i have found you remove sigmoid function and binary_cross entropy. as per tutorial i learned sigmoind has to be at end. but anyways these issue is really out of my imaginary at this beginning stage. Thanks a lot for your help.

So there must be same type of issue to i have made in decision tree or other python file that is out of my capacity to find and resolve. please help me, thanks again for your time and effort